# Extension of ideals in polynomial ring extension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $K\subset L$ be a field extension and let $I$ be an ideal of the polynomial ring $K[X_1,...,X_n]$. I want to show that if $1\in J=IL[X_1,...,X_n]$ then $1\in I$. ($J$ is the ideal of $L[X_1,...,X_n]$ generated by the elements of $I$.)

For the case $K$ is an algebraically closed field, i suppose that $1\notin I$ then there exist a maximal ideal $m$ of $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ such that $I\subset m$ and we know that in this case $m=(X_1-a_1,...,X_n-a_n)$ for some $(a_1,...,a_n)\in K^n$ and we continue in this way we get a contradiction... Now i don't know what to do if $K$ is not necessarily algebraically closed field. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$L[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is a *faithfully flat* $K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$-algebra, hence
$$IL[X_1,\dots,X_n]\cap K[X_1,\dots,X_n]=I.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this quick proof. I'm looking for a proof according to the best of my knowledge... but i see your proof hides a lot of important thing, so i ask if you can send some reference to see this in details.

Comment: Here are two: Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, Ch.3 *Properties of Ring Extensions*, theorem 7.5. Also Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, ch. I, *Flat Modules*,  §3 (*Faithfully Flat Modules*), n°5, proposition 8.